# debug jQuery form validation plugin

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation

My ASP.NET site uses jQuery form [validation plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/validate) v1.8.1 with jQuery 1.6.1. It's only working correctly in FF3, not working in GC14 or IE8, by that I mean after clicking submit button, it appears nothing happens - no `error` class being added, all fields have been reset. However, it did validate the form, just not adding error class and reserving the form data.

I've tried to enable debug flag like `$('form').validate({debug:true});`, however there's no error log in error console. Is there any way to figure out this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the browser's error console - there might be a hint about what's going on (exceptions, ...).

Otherwise, you will have to step into the `validate` method and figure out why nothing happens.